# Usage of IIS URL Rewrite module

Tags: angular, iis, deployment

Can we use IIS URL rewrite module for commercial usage? I have an angular app that I want to deploy in IIS. But my company had asked for alternatives saying IIS URL Rewrite module? Is it true it cannot be used for commercial purposes? Are there any alternatives to deploy angular app in IIS?

Comment: Any IIS out-of-band components, URL Rewrite/ARR/ASP.NET Core module, are considered part of Windows, so they are fully supported by Microsoft and you can use them for free. So I wonder who said they cannot be used for commercial usage, at least Microsoft never says that. BTW, its installer comes with a clear EULA so advice from a lawyer is the most straight forward thing you should chase now.

Comment: Regarding whether the IIS URL Rewrite module can be used commercially, You can retrieve various Microsoft EULA documents from [Microsoft License Terms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/useterms). If you want to deploy the angular app to iis without using url rewrite,  Then the request cannot be redirected to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can use. IIS Re-write module is an extension of IIS. As long as you have the licensed microsoft windows OS you can install and use this extension. Terms of usage is available in the [link](https://www.iis.net/community/files/EULA/URL_REWRITE_RTW.html)